# ConnectionReceived never called

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

No exceptions are thrown and the connection isn't rejected. So I'm doing something wrong on the thread creation probably.

```
// UI Thread
Task.Run(() => CreateRoom());
// ...

public async void CreateRoom()
{
    StreamSocketListener _listener = new StreamSocketListener();
    _listener.ConnectionReceived += ParsePackets;
    await _listener.BindServiceNameAsync("5000");
}

private void ParsePackets(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        var messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Player joined.");
        messageDialog.ShowAsync();
    });
}
```

Comment: Try connecting from the same App or another device. Connecting from another process in the same machine is not supported.

Comment: @klewic Whoa! That was it. Do you want to make it an answer so I can upvote you and mark this as closed? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamSocketListener` does not support connections from other processes in the same machine. Not even with a [loopback exemption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx).

Try connecting from another device or from the same app.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from kiewic worked for me on one machine, but on another machine this did not work. It turns out that this other machine had a VM on it that had a virtual Ethernet adapter. the `StreamSocketListener` was listening to this virtual adapter, and I was unable to connect to the virtual adapter from another machine. Removing the virtual Ethernet adapter fixed the issue.

I figured this out by using the "CheckNetIsolation" tool on this [msdn page about troubleshooting network isolation issues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx).

Just wanted to add this answer in case the answer from kiewic doesn't work.